# Alternative to File.WriteAllText?

Tags: c#

My app has to write a text into a file thousands of time per second using File.WriteAllText. There is less than 10 bytes each time (a number string to be exact). I test my app by ending its process using Task Manager. Some time I get a empty file.

I think the function empty the file before writing to it. And the process has been ended in the middle.

Which is better, reliable way to save a small text into a file?

```
    long ServerSequence
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_serverSeqFlag)
            {
                return _serverSequence;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_serverSeqFlag)
            {
                _serverSequence = value;
                File.WriteAllText(_DayOutputPath + "server.seq", _serverSequence.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242567/discussion-on-question-by-quangnd-alternative-to-file-writealltext).

Answer (score 1):

File is not a good choice for high frequency reading and writing. It does not make sense to write a file thousands of times per second. Other processes hardly can read it as the file is occupied by your writing process. Why not use database? Or You can place the data in a variable in the memory and write it into the file when the process ends. Redis maybe a good choice for your scenario.

Comment: using DB is not a good choice for us here. The performance is poor.

Comment: `You can place the data in a variable in the memory` that's what the code already does `and write it into the file when the process ends` in that case all the data will be lost. Using Redis is the only thing that could work

Comment: you mean redis or the server that hosts redis won't crash?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we simulate a case when servers lost power, every thing stop. (Server has raid card and raid battery)

Comment: @QuangND so the real question is recovery, not perf. The text file is your "backup". Please explain all this in the question itself. It matters. Transaction logs are append-only for a reason - if you overwrite the file, there won't be any data left to recover after a crash. Redis uses an [append only file](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) to handle crashes for example. This way, even if the service crashes, Redis can replay the file up to the last valid record. Redis has built-in support for sequences too - but the cross-process call will have a slight overhead

Comment: @Lei Yang  It is meaningless to argue crash. Even the hard drive could crash.  The key point is to add logic to make up for the crash.

Comment: sure. but he says it is the ONLY thing that could work. and i don't understand redis as a memory storage could prevent such data lost. can anyone explain why redis is sufficient for data persistence?

Comment: @LeiYang Redis [offers persistence and various levels of recovery](https://redis.io/topics/persistence). It's a good idea if there are multiple clients, but it's far too much if one only wants to persist a single sequence value

Comment: i won't be arguing with you anymore.

Comment: @LeiYang you haven't understood the problem yet. The OP hasn't explained it clearly yet. It looks like the sequence value actually comes from a server-side SEQUENCE object, which means a database is *already* used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I implement some kind of server/client protocol so the client has to keep track of both client and server sequence.

Comment: @QuangND explain the actual problem in the question itself. Trying to implement eg FIX or Swift, where the message sequence number is important, is different from `how do I write a file to disk?`. There are several open source Flex libraries too, you could check how they do it. At the most basic though, ensure you write the sequence *before* you use it

Comment: @QuangND it's always possible to lose data though, so FIX provides a way for clients and servers to recover if they're out of sequence.